# CQ5/AEM - Certain links are not rewriting

Tags: aem

We're experiencing some inconsistency with URLs on our publish instance. Some links are having  the /content/project/ removed whilst others are not.

The /etc/map has been created and seems to be working as expected, except for these links.

An example of where the rewriting is links in the OOTB Text component.
Just highlighted the text and used the hyperlink in the RTE.
The output HTML on publish comes through as the desired

`<a adhocenable="false" href="/path/support.html">My Link</a>`

A link that's not being rewritten is from a component, in it's dialog we have a richtext xtype that is referenced in the jsp

```
<cq:text property="description">
```

This however is output on the publish as:

```
<a adhocenable="false" href="/content/project/path/support.html">Other Link</a>
```

I've had a look in /system/console/configMgr and the Day CQ Link Transformer Checker and this has a:href, area:href, from:action, input:value. So I thought this would pick up the links under anchors.

If anyone can suggest where I should be looking to resolve this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the hyperlink functionality in both instances?  Perhaps if you write the link out in the html editor instead of using the link button, the link is not rewritten properly.  Perhaps the hyperlink functionality takes advantage of resourceResolver.map().

Comment: How do I remove the adhocenable attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further investigations I noticed that the links that were not working were contained in  tags, and therefore not rewritten by AEM